# Создание таблицы

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Здравствуйте, в чем тут ошибка?

```
CREATE TABLE accountTable
(
    accountid INTEGER NOT NULL,
    userid INTEGER,
    accountbalance DOUBLE PRECISION,
    accounttype VARCHAR(20),
    admintype BOOLEAN,
    CONSTRAINT accountTable_pk PRIMARY KEY(accountid)
);
```

Выводит следующее:

> Error report -
>   SQL Error: ORA-00902: invalid datatype
>   00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"

Comment: Может [поэтому](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518415/boolean-giving-invalid-datatype-oracle) ? И [ещё](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/datatypes.htm#LNPLS348)

Comment: @nobody спасибо, исправил.
А можете подсказать, в чем тут ошибка?
<blink>
    CREATE TABLE accountTable
    (
        accountid INTEGER NOT NULL,
        userid INTEGER,
        accountbalance DOUBLE,
        accounttype VARCHAR(20),
        admintype CHAR,
        CONSTRAINT accountTable_pk PRIMARY KEY(accountid),
        CONSTRAINT accountTable_fk FOREIGN KEY(userid)
        REFERENCES userTable(user_id)
    );
</blink>
"missing keyword"

Comment: Пожалуйста. После `DOUBLE` не хватает `PRECISION` , полагаю. Подробно [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36424030/create-table-sql-error-ora-00905-missing-keyword).

Comment: @nobody спасибо. в T-SQL как-то проще. буду разбираться))

Comment: Вы слишком заморачиваетесь с числовыми типами. Используйте NUMBER с указанием размерности, например баланс наверняка требует только 2 знака после запятой, сделайте его скажем `NUMBER(11,2)` так надежнее. Судя по доке `double precision` реализован именно на number, но он же мог быть форматом с плавающей точкой, в котором деньги нельзя хранить ни в одной СУБД потому как у него не абсолютная точность, а примерная ...

Comment: Кстати `INTEGER` в oraсle это `NUMBER(38)`. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm

Comment: @Mike спасибо, так и сделаю))

Answer (score 1):

Проблема - тип Boolean в таблице. Этот тип часто используется в pl/sql, но у Oracle его нельзя использовать в "обычном" sql (операторах dml/ddl), ни при создании объектов, ни при  запросах/апдейтах/вставках.

В данном случае проще заменить этот тип на, например, varchar2(1) с констрейнтом check(имяполя in ('Y', 'N'))